# Making a picture with x's and spaces in multiple rows based on user input

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm doing some homework for computer programming (Year 8 in the UK). Here are the criteria for the program:
Write a function that takes two numbers.
The first number indicates the number of spaces that should be displayed and the second indicates the number of Xs that should be displayed. These should both be displayed on the same line. 
Now write another function that makes multiple calls to your first function and draws a picture with Xs. 
My code is as follows:

```
number_of_spaces=int(input("How many spaces?"))
how_many_xs=int(input("How may x's"))
how_many_lines=int(input("How many lines of this?"))
def one_line(x,y):
    print(' '*x,'x'*y)
one_line(number_of_spaces,how_many_xs)
def picture(x,y,z):
    print((one_line(number_of_spaces,how_many_xs))*z)
picture(number_of_spaces,how_many_xs,how_many_lines)
```

Here is what python gives back with the value of all three variables at five:

```
How many spaces?5
How may x's5
How many lines of this?5
      xxxxx
      xxxxx
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python34\task 24.py", line 9, in <module>
    picture(number_of_spaces,how_many_xs,how_many_lines)
  File "C:\Python34\task 24.py", line 8, in picture
    print((one_line(number_of_spaces,how_many_xs))*z)
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for *: 'NoneType' and 'int'
```

I tried changing the format of the variable 'how_many_lines' to float and I got a similar error message except it said unsupported for `NoneType` and `float` instead. With format `str` for variable 'how_many_lines' I get the error message:

`TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'NoneType'`

Any help would be appreciated and anything to help me avoid running into this in the future.

Comment: `one_line` should not print, but rather return `' '*x,'x'*y`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure that the end result can be described as a picture but this seems to do what you're describing.
The previous answers are essentially giving lists of characters not printing them out as text "art".

```
number_of_spaces=int(input("How many spaces?"))
how_many_xs=int(input("How may x's"))
how_many_lines=int(input("How many lines of this?"))


def one_line(x,y):
    print(' '*x,'x'*y)
    return ""


def picture(number_of_spaces, how_many_xs, how_many_lines):
    for i in range(0,how_many_lines):
        print(' ' * number_of_spaces, 'x' * how_many_xs)


picture(number_of_spaces, how_many_xs, how_many_lines)
```

Comment: I will try this too and reply if it works or not. Thank you this works better actually.

Answer (score 1):

Your `one_line()` function doesn't explicitly return anything, so it effectively returns `None` (of type `NoneValue`).

Try changing as indicated below:

```
def one_line(x, y):
#    print(' '*x, 'x'*y)
    return ' '*x, 'x'*y
```